# Related rates of change involving trig functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, implicit-differentiation, related-rates

> Question: A train is moving along a straight track at
> $75 \text{km h}^{-1}$ heading east. A camera is positioned $2$km north of the train track and is focused on the train.
>
> a) Find the rate of change of the distance between the camera and the train when the train is $4$km from the camera.
>
> b) Find the rate at which the camera is rotating when the train is 4km from the camera. Give your answer in degrees per second correct to the nearest tenth of a degree.

This is a question that has caused my extension maths group a bit of confusion! We have solved part a of the question and we believe the answer is $65$km/h (2sf). This is correct.
Part b is the one we are unsure about. We have set up the problem using a couple of variables and applied various differentiation techniques. The answers we are getting, however, are varied and even our teacher has said that he needs a bit more time to work out which one is correct! I am quite eager to find out whether my technique is correct. The different answers we have got are:

- $2.6 \times 10^{-3}$ radians/second (then we can convert this to degrees per second as the question asks)
- $2.6$ degrees/second

I appreciate that by putting this question out there, I may generate different responses, so I will wait to see if a several people start getting the same answer before accepting if it is correct.

Best wishes!

Comment: We need to know the steps you took to arrive at the solution in order to tell whether your technique/method is correct.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.  Also, please type your questions, rather than posting images.  images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: @saulspatz - done!

Comment: In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be surround by `$` signs.  `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$

Comment: The answer I obtained is the first one ($2.6 \times 10^{-3}$ rad/s). Do you know how your groupmates arrived at the second solution?

Comment: @player3236 Yes, I think I have some of their working t perhaps - I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll illustrate a general solution to the problem since you seem to be enthusiastic about this topic. Below is a diagram of the situation:
[image]

$x$ is the distance of the train to the perpendicular, $d$ is the distance to the observer, $v$ is the train's speed (constant), $s$ is the distance of the train to the observer, and $\theta$ is the angle the train makes with the perpendicular, some number in the open interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. I'll use dots to denote time derivatives. We know that the train moves at speed $v$, in other words
$$\dot{x}=v$$
We also know, from Pythagoras, that
$$x^2+d^2=s^2$$
So,
$$2s\dot{s}=2x\dot{x}\implies \dot{s}=\frac{x\dot{x}}{s}=\frac{x\dot{x}}{\sqrt{x^2+d^2}}=\frac{xv}{\sqrt{x^2+d^2}}$$
So, if $d=2\text{ km}$, $v=75\text{ km h}^{-1}$ and $x=\pm 4\text{ km}$ we get
$$\dot{s}=\frac{\pm 4\cdot 75}{\sqrt{4^2+2^2}}\text{ km h}^{-1}=\frac{\pm 4}{\sqrt{20}}\cdot 75\text{ km h}^{-1}\approx 67\text{ km h}^{-1}$$

Onto the second part. For this part I'll take positive $x$ on the right. With trigonometry we see that
$$\tan(\theta)=\frac{x}{d}\implies \theta=\arctan\left(\frac{x}{d}\right)$$
Taking time derivatives of both sides we get
$$\sec^2(\theta)\dot{\theta}=\frac{\dot{x}}{d}$$
Now using our expression for $\theta$ and the fact that $\dot{x}=v$,
$$\dot{\theta}=\frac{v}{d~\sec^2\left(\arctan\left(\frac{x}{d}\right)\right)}=\frac{v}{d\left(\frac{x^2}{d^2}+1\right)}=\frac{vd}{x^2+d^2}=\frac{vd}{s^2}$$
I'll leave it as an exercise to prove that
$$\sec(\arctan(t))=\sqrt{t^2+1}$$
Using $v=75\text{ km h}^{-1}$, $s=4\text{ km}$, and $d=2\text{ km}$ we get
$$\dot{\theta}=\frac{75\cdot 2}{4^2}\text{ radians h}^{-1}\approx 0.149\text{ degrees s}^{-1}$$

I don't think either of the provided answers are correct.

Comment: Your answer is equivalent to $2.6\times 10^{-3}$ rad/s obtained using OP's method below.

Comment: @player3236 Whoops, I suppose I was only paying attention to the deg/s part. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, $75 \text{km h}^{-1} = \frac1{48} \text{km s}^{-1}$

Draw a right angled triangle with the triangle 'pointing' right.
Label the top vertex $A$, and then $B$ and $C$ will follow in clockwise fashion.

$AC = 2$km. The rate of change of $BC$ is $\frac1{48}  \text{km s}^{-1}$ and $BC$ is $\frac1{48} t $ km (I assume this comes from speed = distance*time?).

Let $\angle BAC = \theta$.

Then $\tan(\theta) = \frac1{96}t$ and, differentiating both sides with respect to $t$, we get $\frac1{cos^2\theta}\frac {d\theta}{dx} = 1/96$

We can know divide both sides and work out an expression.
We can also work out the value of $\cos \theta$ by plugging in that the hypotenuse is $4$ and so work out $\cos^2 \theta$. Thus, we can plug this value into our expression for $\frac {d\theta}{dt}$, which gives them $1/4 \times 1/96 = 1/384 = 2.6$ degrees per second (?)

Sorry I don't have the complete working.

Comment: Actually, wait! I have just put 1/384 into my calculator but that doesn't give 2.6 degrees...I'm afraid I don't have the full working then.

Comment: $1/384$ is the $2.6 \times 10^{-3}$ rad/s value we are looking for. This is also very similar to the way I arrived at the solution. Now we just need to convert this to degrees per second.